# Check in a tpl-if-tag, if characters are chinese in a gxt template

Tags: java, templates, gxt

in my java gxt-project, I have a template, in which I have the following tpl tags, which decide, depending on a parenttitle, if the title has to be italics.

```
                <tpl if="titleORG != &quot;&quot;">
                <tpl if="ParentTitleORG == &quot;&quot;"><i></tpl>
                <b>{titleORG}<tpl if="subtitleORG != &quot;&quot;">: {subtitleORG}</tpl></b>
                <tpl if="ParentTitleORG == &quot;&quot;"></i></tpl>
                </tpl>
                <tpl if="titleEN != &quot;&quot;">
                    <tpl if="officialTitleTranslation"> / {titleEN}<tpl if="subtitleEN != &quot;&quot;">: {subtitleEN}</tpl></tpl>
                </tpl>.
```

Lately, I got a ticket, whether it is possible to make title italics only, if they are not chinese or korean.

Any idea, how I can check for that?

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to check it in the Class you pass into the XTemplate.

Add a boolean (I'll call it ckj) and set it in your constructor. [Using the Person example from GXT documentation]

```
  public class Person {
    private String name;
    private boolean ckj;
    private int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
      this.ckj=containsJapanese(name);
    }
    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
      return age;
    }

    public boolean containsCKJ(String s) {
    return s.codePoints()
            .anyMatch(codepoint -> (Character.UnicodeScript.of(codepoint) == Character.UnicodeScript.HAN
                    || Character.UnicodeBlock.of(codepoint) == Character.UnicodeBlock.CJK_UNIFIED_IDEOGRAPHS
                    || Character.UnicodeBlock.of(codepoint) == Character.UnicodeBlock.CJK_UNIFIED_IDEOGRAPHS_EXTENSION_A
                    || Character.UnicodeBlock.of(codepoint) == Character.UnicodeBlock.CJK_UNIFIED_IDEOGRAPHS_EXTENSION_B
                    || Character.UnicodeBlock.of(codepoint) == Character.UnicodeBlock.CJK_UNIFIED_IDEOGRAPHS_EXTENSION_C                    
                    || Character.UnicodeBlock.of(codepoint) == Character.UnicodeBlock.CJK_UNIFIED_IDEOGRAPHS_EXTENSION_D                                                        
                    || Character.UnicodeBlock.of(codepoint) == Character.UnicodeBlock.CJK_COMPATIBILITY
                    || Character.UnicodeBlock.of(codepoint) == Character.UnicodeBlock.CJK_COMPATIBILITY_FORMS
                    || Character.UnicodeBlock.of(codepoint) == Character.UnicodeBlock.CJK_COMPATIBILITY_IDEOGRAPHS
                    || Character.UnicodeBlock.of(codepoint) == Character.UnicodeBlock.CJK_COMPATIBILITY_IDEOGRAPHS_SUPPLEMENT
                    || Character.UnicodeBlock.of(codepoint) == Character.UnicodeBlock.CJK_RADICALS_SUPPLEMENT
                    || Character.UnicodeBlock.of(codepoint) == Character.UnicodeBlock.CJK_STROKES
                    || Character.UnicodeBlock.of(codepoint) == Character.UnicodeBlock.CJK_SYMBOLS_AND_PUNCTUATION
                    || Character.UnicodeBlock.of(codepoint) == Character.UnicodeBlock.ENCLOSED_CJK_LETTERS_AND_MONTHS
                    || Character.UnicodeBlock.of(codepoint) == Character.UnicodeBlock.ENCLOSED_IDEOGRAPHIC_SUPPLEMENT                                                                                           
                    || Character.UnicodeBlock.of(codepoint) == Character.UnicodeBlock.KANGXI_RADICALS
                    || Character.UnicodeBlock.of(codepoint) == Character.UnicodeBlock.IDEOGRAPHIC_DESCRIPTION_CHARACTERS

            ));
     }
  }
```

Then you can use an if expression in your template.

```
 <tpl if="!ckj">
 //italics
 <tpl if="ckj">
 //no italics
```

More discussion on checking for CKJ characters is here [Differentiating CJK languages (Chinese, Japanese, Korean) in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41982073/differentiating-cjk-languages-chinese-japanese-korean-in-android)